# insert image in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

plz , can anyone help in this code ??

```
string imagename="test.png";
        string imagepath=Server.MapPath("\\images");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder S = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("data source=hima-pc\\sql8;initial catalog=test; integrated security= True;pooling=false ");
        con.ConnectionString = S.ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        string sqlcon = "insert into images(imgname,imgpath)values("+imagename+","+imagepath+")";

        SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand(sqlcon,con);
        int numrow = myCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

plz i need to save the path of image in my database 
but without uploadfile
my image is already in the folder in server

Comment: And what is the problem? Is there an error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like ' are missing

```
string sqlcon = "insert into images(imgname,imgpath)values('"+imagename+"','"+imagepath+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your SQL-Statement:

1. The ' are missing.
2. Between the table(columns..) and VALUES the space is missing:

   ```
   string sqlcon = "INSERT INTO images(imgname,imgpath) VALUES ('"+imagename+"','"+imagepath+"');";
   ```

Take a look at this:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

It describes the INSERT INTO Statement.